# Sharing information to Facebook(wall), Twitter(status), Google plus

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus, rhodes, rhomobile

In my application I need to share some information to  Facebook(wall), Twitter(status), Google Plus
If user click the share button , after posting to the facebook or twitter , then user should be redirect to the application.

How to do this in rhomobile, Is there any tutorial to to this ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook: [Post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Twitter: [Statuses](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update)

Google Plus has read-only API for nowadays.